# technical computing : Is the CPU instruction per cycle and flops per cycle is same ?

Tags: cluster-computing

Is the CPU instruction per cycle and flops per cycle is same ?

how to find CPU instruction per cycle of the cpu ?

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2540M CPU @ 2.60GHz

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not the same.

[FLOPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flops) is floating point operations per second. This is used as a measurement because historically floating point operations has been very expensive operations compared to other operations.

[Instructions per cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instructions_per_cycle) would be an average of any kind of instruction executed per cycle. You would need a specific test case to measure that, as the number of instructions that can be performed per cycle varies much depending on what the instruction does. For example, if the first instruction performed would be a branch, and the CPU didn't predict the branch correctly, that would be the only instruction that would be executed that cycle.

On [this page](http://setiathome.berkeley.edu/cpu_list.php) you can find that the specific processor has this measured speed:

```
2.42 GFLOPS/core
9.65 GFLOPS/computer
```

This is giga-floating operations per second. You would divide that with the CPU frequency if you wanted that as FLO per cycle.

Comment: The flops numbers sited on that page are woefully off-base.  The processor in question is a Sandybridge with turbo to 3.3 GHz, so Rmax/core is (3.3 gigacycles / second) * (2 vector operations / cycle) * (4 double precision flops / vector operation) = 26.4 GFLOPS/core (double that figure for single-precision).  Achieved Rpeak will vary depending on workload, but for compute intensive tasks that have been optimized, it should generally exceed 40 GFLOPS when using both cores.  Otherwise, good answer (though it should be pointed out that a single instruction can represent multiple flops as well).